# Guidelines for the development of web Gis Application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, web, gis

Respected Sir/Mam

I want to Develop a Webgis application and want to know the right path to move ahead, So that I will start work smoothly.I am good in .net , c#, jquery, HTML, Azax etc. Actually I am working on a project where data is already preset in shp files, Digitized in Arc-Gis,Some data in sql server. I am confuse how can I develop a application where I will use this data and display on the map

Below are Some queries need to discuss.

1. How can I integrate the data(present in shp file,sql Server and excel) with front end, to display the data in the Map.
2. Is there any open Source which I need to integrate in the project for displaying data in the Map Window and which good for integration with .net . where i can perform several function like Zoom in, zoom out,search etc.
3. Is there any middleware for accessing data from shp file in project.

Rest I will ask when I will be in a confident about it,

I am requesting you please help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Please see some ideas below set out to answer your questions.

1. I think the way to integrate the most amount of data sources is probably with the the OpenGeo Suit. This is an open source software stack that includes Geoserver as a WMS source and GXP libraries and examples as the front end client. It can be found here http://opengeo.org/
2. There are a number of Open source projects out there that will help. I have already mentioned OpenGeo. Also check out 
   Openlayers http://openlayers.org/
   GeoExt (Can't post link as I don't have enough reputation points yet)
   Leaflet (Can't post link as I don't have enough reputation points yet)
3. Geoserver is a good one for this but you could also checkout
   Mapserver (Can't post link as I don't have enough reputation points yet)

In summary I would recommend the OpenGeo stuff as it includes the front end JavaScript libraries including Openlayers and GeoExt giving you lots of scope and Flexibility. It also includes some nice back end stuff with geoserver for connecting to multiple data sources and integrating security ect. I have had a lot of success with it.

Answer (score 0):

As you wish I also wished to develop a web gis application and I could complete it with SVG graphics. The polygon data and point data in ArcGIS are converted into Asc format files which looks like as follows:

```
Polygon
17671 0
0 77.5946807861 11.9351053238 1.#QNAN 1.#QNAN
1 77.5961227417 11.9347372055 1.#QNAN 1.#QNAN
2 77.5976333618 11.9341630936 1.#QNAN 1.#QNAN
3 77.5994033813 11.933801651 1.#QNAN 1.#QNAN
```

The above polygon will have 17671 points. They are all nothing but point no: longitude latitude in space delimited format and some extra things which I don't consider.
Similarly point objects will be exported in Asc format files and it looks as

```
Point
0 77.5946807861 11.9351053238 1.#QNAN 1.#QNAN
Point
0 77.5961227417 11.9347372055 1.#QNAN 1.#QNAN
```

.
I just converted those polylines and points into integer values with reference to fixed latitude and logitude and make them into seperate xml files.
The properties of point objects and polygons copied and saved into Excel sheets. Then I made them into a simple ^ seperated database. 
Then I made my GIS application and published it in my blog [http://mksugumaran.blogspot.in/2014/04/svg-scalable-vector-graphics-in-web-page.html](http://www.nirt.in/tnbasins.xml)

The source code of the above main webpage view-source:http://www.nirt.in/xmlsvg.htm is

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Tamilnadu Rainfall data in GIS</title>
<style>
p.pos_fixed1
{
FONT: bold 14px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
COLOR: #000066;
position:fixed;
top:30px;
left:20px;
z-index=10;
}
p.pos_fixed2
{
FONT: bold 14px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
COLOR: #000066;
position:fixed;
top:45px;
left:20px;
z-index=10;
}
iframe.pos_fixed3
{
top:75px;
left:0px;
position:fixed;
width:250px;
height:300px;
}
</style>
<script language="javascript">
var aHexArray="0123456789ABCDEF";
var LLXC=75.0;
var LUYC=13.5833332538605;
var CS=0.00083333333333333;
var x1 = new Array();
var y1 = new Array();
var n1,ild;
var i,j;
var nx;
function fnRandomDec(){
var iMaxDec=256;
var iRandDec=parseInt((iMaxDec*Math.random())-1);
return iRandDec;
}
function fnReturnHex(iDecValue){
return aHexArray.charAt((iDecValue>>4)&0xf)+aHexArray.charAt(iDecValue&0xf);
}
function fnRandColor(){
return "#" + fnReturnHex(fnRandomDec()) + fnReturnHex(fnRandomDec()) + fnReturnHex(fnRandomDec());
}

function drawing(zx)
{
var txt1;
txt1=""
y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].childNodes;
//document.write(y.length-1);
//document.write("<svg onclick=fnchange(); width='" + Math.round(6700/zx) + "' height='" + Math.round(6700/zx) + "'>");

txt1= txt1 + "<svg style=z-index:2; width='" + Math.round(6700/zx) + "' height='" + Math.round(6700/zx) + "' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>";
for (j=0;j<y.length;j++)
{
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Polygon")[j].childNodes;
//document.write(x.length-1);
//document.write("<polygon points='");
name=x[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
txt1=txt1 + "<a xlink:title=" + name + " xlink:href='wdb4x.asp?dbname=tnrfs&2=xx'" + " target='xy1'>"
txt1= txt1 + "<polygon points='";
for (i=1;i<x.length;i++)
{
  gxy=x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  n1=gxy.indexOf(",");
  x1[i]=gxy.substr(0,n1);
  y1[i]=gxy.substr(n1+1);
  txt1= txt1 +Math.round(x1[i]/zx)+','+Math.round(y1[i]/zx)+' '
}

txt1=txt1 +"' style='fill:" + fnRandColor() + ";stroke:black;stroke-width:1'></polygon></a>";
}
colr=fnRandColor();
y=xmlDoc1.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].childNodes;
for (j=0;j<y.length;j++)
{
x=xmlDoc1.getElementsByTagName("point")[j].childNodes;
name=x[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
gxy=x[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
n1=gxy.indexOf(",");
xx1=gxy.substr(0,n1);
yy1=gxy.substr(n1+1);
str1=name + ':' + Math.abs(LUYC-yy1*CS) + ',' + Math.abs(LLXC+xx1*CS);
txt1=txt1 + "<a xlink:title=" + str1 + " xlink:href='wdb4x.asp?dbname=tnrfs&2=" + name + "' target='xy1'"+"'>";

txt1=txt1 + "<circle cx='" + Math.round(xx1/zx) +"' cy='" + Math.round(yy1/zx) + "' r='5' stroke='black' stroke-width='1' fill='"+ fnRandColor() +"'></circle></a>";
}
txt1=txt1 + "</svg>";
scr1.innerHTML=txt1;
}
function position3(xx1,yy1)
{
xy1.style.top=Math.round(yy1/zx);
xy1.style.left=Math.round(xx1/zx);
}
function fnchange()
{
nx=nx-1;
if(nx==0)nx=1;
drawing(nx);
}
function fnchange1()
{
nx=nx+1;
if(nx>10)nx=10;
drawing(nx);
}

function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}
function loadXMLString(txt)
{
if (window.DOMParser)
  {
  parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
  }
else // Internet Explorer
  {
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async=false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
  }
return xmlDoc;
}
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("tnbasins.xml");
xmlDoc1=loadXMLDoc("tnrfl.xml");

</script>
</head>
<body>

<p class="pos_fixed1" onclick="fnchange1();">zoom_out</p>
<p class="pos_fixed2" onclick="fnchange();">zoom_in</p>
<iframe class="pos_fixed3" style=width:250;height:300;z-index:1; z-index=-1; name=xy1 border=none frameborder=none></iframe>
<table><tr><td id=scr1></td></tr></table>
<script language="javascript">
if (xmlDoc && xmlDoc1)
{
nx=10;
drawing(nx);
}
</SCRIPT>

</body>
</html>
```

The polygon xml file is in the link http://www.nirt.in/tnbasins.xml

The point objects xml file is in the link  http://www.nirt.in/tnrfl.xml

The link of web gis application is http://www.nirt.in/xmlsvg.htm